# ReactJS code not working after implementing Flux technique

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a simple ToDo application in ReactJS using React's Flux technique. But when I run my code, I am getting an error that is `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I have tried some available solutions like replacing `import` with `require` but the issue is not being solved. Please tell how to solve this issue? The complete code is posted below. (All of the code files are in the same directory).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Flux</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script> var exports = {}; </script>
    <script src="Todos.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Todos.js**

```
import Todo from "./Todo";
import TodoStore from "./TodoStore";

export default class Featured extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            todos: TodoStore.getAll(),
        };
    }
    render() {
        const { todos } = this.state;
        const TodoComponents = todos.map((todo) => {
            return <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo}/>;
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Todos</h1>
                <ul>{TodoComponents}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

React.render(<Featured/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

**TodoStore.js**

```
import {EventEmitter} from "events";

class TodoStore extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.todos = [
            {
                id: 111,
                text: "Go Shoping",
                complete: false
            },
            {
                id: 222,
                text: "Pay Bills",
                complete: false
            },
        ];
    }
    getAll() {
        return this.todos;
    }
}

const todoStore = new TodoStore;

export default todoStore;
```

**Todo.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        const { complete, edit, text } = this.props;

        const icon = complete ? "true icon" : "false icon"

        if (edit) {
            return (
                <li>
                    <input value={text} focus="focused"/>
                </li>
            );
        }

        return (
            <li>
                <span>{text}</span>
                <span>{icon}</span>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are using any bundling tools such browserify, webpack, or rollup.js? `require` or `import` is not available without them.

Comment: I would look into create-react-app to get started instead of wiring up a script tag in the html like you have